Linux psysical memory and swap in production
I wanted to have an opinion from anybody about my production server swapiness and physical ram sharing into services.
This server configuration has OS 22.04 ubuntu with 128GB RAM. It is a dedicated server not a vps.
It hosts a php application and run the following services:

Nginx 1.26.2
Varnish 7.5 run in socket
Redis 7.4.1 run in socket
PHP8.3 FPM
Rabbitmq 3.13.7
ElasticSearch 8.11.4
Percona mysql 8.0.39-30
Hitch 1.8

All above services have of course custom configurations which included the amount of memory should be used.
For this server I have configure a swap file of 64GB. Of course I have given no priority to system to use this SWAP
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file       64G 2.8G   -2
/dev/md0  partition   4G   0B   -3

cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
10

and
/etc/sysctl.conf
vm.swappiness=10
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=90
vm.overcommit_memory = 1

RAM free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          128731       46517        7285         953       74928       79952
Swap:          69626        2882       66744

You will notice that I have around 2.8GB of swap used. As far as I know OS to use SWAP must have full RAM.
With this bash script:
for file in /proc/*/status; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 2 -n -r | less

I see that nginx, php8.3, Elasticsearch, redis and hitch use SWAP
Also I see in RAM that there is around 7GB free. Also I see that buff/cache uses 75GB of RAM.
Here come the questions:

How I can prevent OS to use SWAP?
Can someone explain what is buff/cache? Is this reserve RAM. Is this related with Varnish? How I control this section of RAM?


Why do you not want to use swap? It frees up memory for things that are actually used? Why do you want to control RAM use? Linux handles it just fine.

There is no indication that RAM usage is a problem. You have 80GB of 128GB available. If your appplications have problems, describe them.

@GeraldSchneider you are right. Thanks for clarified this

Why having so much swap? I literally never observed a system that operates normally and uses more that 4 GiB of swap. It's really for the unused bits, like services that do something once per week and fall down into swap for the rest of the life, there can't be 68 GiB of them. Observe your system, probably you don't need that swap file.
